Effect of coupling factor in flyback converter relative to rectifying diode
I'm simulating a CCM flyback converter on ltspice, and I need some help in understanding the results when I decreased the coupling factor from 1 to 0.96.
When K=1, the voltage appearing across the diode is normal and coinciding with my calculations of the reverse voltage.
What I don't understand is the voltage spike that appears when K=0.96, can someone explain it to me?
Note: I already understand the ringing effect that happened in the primary side across the MOSFET.

What did you expect to see when leakage was introduced?

If you understand the spike on the primary, ask yourself what the difference is?  You have current in the secondary's self-inductance, and no current path when the diode is back-biased.  Where does the stored energy go?
